# Why will this not compile?

Tags: java

So the following code has errors

> "go" has no identifier

But I thought when I declared "go" as a String type variable that this gave an identifier to the variable "go"?

Obviously I've got it messed up somewhere as I'm new to Java (and coding in general) so I was wondering how I would identify the variable "go" and resolve the issue in which I'm facing. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
public class ATM {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String ATM;
        ATM myATM = new ATM();
        myATM.go(); 
    }

    public class go {

        String go;
        go = "Welcome to online ATM banking";
        go = "How much do you wan in your account?";
        go = "Enter your number";

        System.outprintln(go);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your inner class has no methods.

Comment: First, you need to format your code. Second, you need to understand what it is your code is trying to do and examine the compile error(s) you got. There are several very basic problems in your code. Properly formatting your code will help in understanding what those problems are.

Comment: Ah okay I see now, I'm trying to declare variables outside of the main method in another class without actually creating a method to define them in. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few trivial issues:

- go is a method not a class
- typo in print statement

Here is complete updated class which compiles.

```
public class ATM {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String ATM;
  ATM myATM = new ATM();
  myATM.go();
 }

 public void go() {

  String go;
  go = "Welcome to online ATM banking";
  go = "How much do you wan in your account?";
  go = "Enter your number";

  System.out.println(go);
 }
}
```

Comment: I think the intended behavior is to have all the strings *concatenated* to `go`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know it was a bad/silly question but you'll have to excuse my lack of knowledge. Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Lee, glad to know that answer is helpful. Please consider accepting the answer.